# how to select nth row within the same tag using Python

Tags: python

[image: picture1]

I want to match the ZIP code and longitude and latitude of each city/county, so I only need:

> New York
>   10001
>   40.748/-73.997

like that.

```
zip_code_NY = soup.find(class_="restable")
ref_raw_1 = [pt.get_text() for pt in zip_code_NY.select("a small")]
city_name = [city.get_text() for city in zip_code_NY.select("tr td")]
name_NY = pd.DataFrame(city_name)
print(name_NY)
```

That's all I could do and this is my output...

[image: picture2]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So what exactly are you missing? Is the last row that you print wrong (where everything is all on one line)? Should we ignore the 0 and 1 you are printing? When you say nth row, which row is that in your example?

Comment: @user7733611 hi, thank you in advance. I only want "New York" and "10001", but as you can see from the first pic, they are all under the same tag so I don't know how to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get 1  element, you can use python list slicing. For example, to select the country, you would do:

First, select the correct table. I can't tell what the parent elements are from the image, but we will assume it is the first table in the html. Then assuming the country is always the 3rd element in the first row in that table:

```
soup.find_all('tr')[0].contents[2]
```

Comment: thanks, that works! I also used [2::9] to get the second lines every 9 lines.